# Translated my theme (translation not showing up)

Tags: themes, translation

I read a lot about what is the optimal to translate your website (french and english in my case)

I set up a Multi site where I created two site one french mywebsite.com/fr and one in english mywebsite.com/en

I am now in the process of translating my theme(in french by default) I added this to my theme function.php:

```
load_theme_textdomain('INTERluminaires', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
```

then modified my template files in order to be able to translate some text

```
<?php _e("Design et conseils", "INTERluminaires"); ?>
```

created a po and mo file with poedit, everything goes well.

I uploaded those files in my theme folder /languages

those files are named en_CA.po and en_CA.mo (I tried INTERluminaires-en_ca.po and mo to no avail)

when I change my theme language in settings general and refresh my website nothing is translated.

any idea what could be wrong here?

btw I managed to translate a plugin I installed without any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incomplete code. You register your Theme's textdomain, but don't actually tell WordPress to *load* your translation files.

To this:

```
load_theme_textdomain('INTERluminaires', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
```

Add this:

```
$locale = get_locale();
$locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";
if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) ) {
    require_once( $locale_file );
}
```

Or, altogether (and wrapped properly in a callback):

```
<?php
function wpse49326_translate_theme() {
    // Load Theme textdomain
    load_theme_textdomain('INTERluminaires', get_template_directory() . '/languages');

    // Include Theme text translation file
    $locale = get_locale();
    $locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";
    if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) ) {
        require_once( $locale_file );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse49326_translate_theme' );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact it works without it. but I'll add it to make sure I was so into my translation that I forgot to upload index.php (rookie mistake!) hence why it was not showing.

Comment: Do you maybe know why Twenty Thirteen doesn't include the second part of this code (with `get_locale()` and `require_once()`)?

Comment: Chip, I realize this is an old question. Doesn't `load_theme_textdomain()` call [`load_textdomain()`](http://queryposts.com/function/load_textdomain/) internally and then requires it by itself and merges it with the global array?